# How to force QActionGroup to allow uncheck?

Tags: qt, pyside

I have a number of actions put together in a QActionGroup, because I want them to be exclusive (if one is checked, all the others should be unchecked). However, I also want to be able to uncheck all of them. At the moment if I check action1, and then click the button again, it will not uncheck, the only way to uncheck it is to click on a different action. In short, QActionGroup ensures exactly 1 of the actions is checked - I want to ensure exactly 1 OR 0 actions are checked. Is there a workaround for this?

I'm using PySide but I'm fairly comfortable with QT in c++ as well, so a solution in c++ would be fine - I'm sure I could convert it.

Code (not very helpful, but I'm posting in case it is relevant)

```
def defineGroups(self):

    navigation = QActionGroup(self)
    navigation.addAction(self.action1)
    navigation.addAction(self.action2)
    navigation.addAction(self.action3)
    navigation.addAction(self.action4)
    navigation.addAction(self.action5)
    navigation.addAction(self.action6)
    navigation.addAction(self.action7)
```

All the actions are checkable (set in QT Designer).

Related:
There is a bug report similar to this, but the designers have decided not to change anything: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-3512

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Qt in C++ instead of Python, but I hope these information could help.

Unfortunately there seems no direct solution to this problem at present. The "exclusive" property of `QActionGroup` limits the feature of selection, which ensures at least and only one action is selected at any one time (but at the begining of the program, you have to manually set one of actions to be "checked")

Here is part of the source code, you can see how it works on `QAction` if the "exclusive" property is installed by `QActionGroup`

```
{
    if ( !isExclusive() )
      return;
    QAction* s = (QAction*) sender();
    if ( b ) {
      if ( s != d->selected ) {
          d->selected = s;
          for ( QPtrListIterator<QAction> it( d->actions); it.current(); ++it ) {
            if ( it.current()->isToggleAction() && it.current() != s )
                it.current()->setOn( FALSE );
          }
          emit activated();
          emit selected( s );
      } else if ( !s->isToggleAction() ) {
          emit activated();
      }
    } else {
      if ( s == d->selected ) {
          // at least one has to be selected
          s->setOn( TRUE );
      }
    }
}
```

(Ref: [http://qt-x11-free.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.3./classQActionGroup_182fe3a5a859e6397a4ba05be346d894.html](http://qt-x11-free.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.3.6/classQActionGroup_182fe3a5a859e6397a4ba05be346d894.html) older version of Qt, but the concept is the same)

(see also: http://qt-x11-free.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.3.6/classQActionGroup_032480c0c57abda9c1b4485ee9edbcc7.html#032480c0c57abda9c1b4485ee9edbcc7)

To solve the problem, at least you have two options:

1. Still use `QActionGroup` and add another `QAction` "None is selected" (or something similar) in your list. This might be the most proper option since it considers "no selection" as a selection and can exploit the feature of `QActionGroup` .
2. Not to use `QActionGroup`. In this case, you have to manually implement the exclusiveness. Once a `QAction` is selected, `emit` a signal that sends a pointer `QAction*` to a `SLOT` which compares the present selection with the previous one from buffer (default = 0), if difference occurs, deselect (use `setCheck(false)`) the previous one and assign the present selection to buffer.

It's just a rough idea, but still feasible if you really need the feature

[EDIT]:
Though I am not sure about the exact functionality you want, I wrote some C++ code here FYR. Notice that this is just a demo of the **"ostensible"** feature of the exclusively checkable QActions and the ability of unchecking any checked one.The according responses of checked/unchecked state still need further implementation.

TheClass.h:

```
class TheClass 
{
    Q_OBJECT  
    ......

public slots:
    void action0Checked();
    void action1Checked();
    void action2Checked();
    void compareChecked(QAction *newChecked);

signals:
    void selectedID(QAction *newChecked);

private:        
    QAction *buffer;
    QList<QAction*> actionList;
}
```

TheClass.cpp:

```
TheClass::TheClass()
{
    QMenuBar *menuBar = new QMenuBar(this); 
    buffer = 0;

    QMenu *menu = menuBar->addMenu("ActionList");
    actionList.append(menu->addAction("Action0"));
    actionList.append(menu->addAction("Action1"));
    actionList.append(menu->addAction("Action2"));

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        actionList[i]->setCheckable(true);
    }

    connect(actionList[0], SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(action0Checked()));
    connect(actionList[1], SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(action1Checked()));
    connect(actionList[2], SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(action2Checked()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(selectedID(QAction*)), this, SLOT(compareChecked(QAction*)));
}

void TheClass::action0Checked()
{
    if (actionList[0]->isChecked()) {
        // do sth.

        emit selectedID(actionList[0]);
    }
}

void TheClass::action1Checked()
{
    if (actionList[1]->isChecked()) {
        // do sth.

        emit selectedID(actionList[1]);
    }
}

void TheClass::action2Checked()
{
    if (actionList[2]->isChecked()) {
        // do sth.

        emit selectedID(actionList[2]);
    }
}

void TheClass::compareChecked(QAction *newChecked)
{
    if (newChecked != buffer) {
        if (buffer != 0)
            buffer->setChecked(false);

        buffer = newChecked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help - I will try the 2nd approach tomorrow (as a "None" option would be out of place in my application).

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to update the post if you have any trouble in trying out the second one.

Comment: Thank you for the code example - it was very helpful. My new class is working as expected. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been some years. But I came across the same issue and found a [nicer solution](https://forum.qt.io/topic/33054/can-you-think-of-a-better-code-to-uncheck-an-action-of-a-qactiongroup/3) in Qt forums. It essentially does this:

```
connect(action_group, &QActionGroup::triggered, [](QAction* action) {
    static QAction* lastAction = nullptr;
    if (action == lastAction)
    {
      action->setChecked(false);
      lastAction = nullptr;
    }
    else
      lastAction = action;
  });
```

Hopefully, it will be useful for the future search of other people.

**EDIT**: as @Joe suggested, this can be further improved with the following code:

```
connect(action_group, &QActionGroup::triggered, [lastAction = static_cast<QAction *>(nullptr)](QAction* action) mutable {
    if (action == lastAction)
    {
      action->setChecked(false);
      lastAction = nullptr;
    }
    else
      lastAction = action;
  });
```

Comment: This could be improved further by capturing `lastAction = static_cast<QAction *>(nullptr)` instead and marking the lambda as `mutable`. Otherwise multiple instances of your window will cause issues.

Comment: I don't understand the part `lastAction = static_cast<QAction *>(nullptr)` should this go in the second line  instead of `static QAction* lastAction = nullptr;` or should it go in the 6th one insted of `lastAction = nullptr;`? Or should it go in both?

Comment: It should go in the capture list of the lambda and replaces the static variable.

Answer (score 0):

As of Qt 5.14 there is the ExclusiveOptional policy:

setExclusionPolicy(QActionGroup::ExclusionPolicy::ExclusiveOptional)

Source: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qactiongroup.html#ExclusionPolicy-enum